# MySQL returned an empty result

Tags: mysql

I want to get a data of previous year : 2015-12-01

My Query :

```
  SELECT 

          catalog.code,
          Max(catalog.weight) as weight, 
          MONTH(product.created_at) as Month, 
          YEAR(product.created_at) as year

  FROM product 

 LEFT JOIN catalog ON product.code = catalog.code

 WHERE MONTH(product.created_at) = MONTH(2016-01-01 - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(product.created_at) = year(NOW())

 GROUP BY catalog.code,MONTH(product.created_at),YEAR(product.created_at)
```

Does anyone have an idea how i can solve this problem?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `where` condition.

Do have a look at [mysql date/datetime formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html), this will give you clear idea of how you should use date functions in mysql.

If you need data of previous year, simply change your where condition to:
**`YEAR(product.created_at) < YEAR(NOW())`**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have the same prob, empty result